# Magento How to remove ?id=value from URL and make seo friendly url

Tags: magento

I am tring to set url without id parameter

right now my url as below which have id parameter and value like this

```
 http://example.com/index.php/brands/acuvue?cat=49 //acuvue which is category name
```

I want to rewrite above url and remove url parameter from url

URL should be like this

```
http://example.com/index.php/brands/acuvue
```

It is possible to fancy_url or .htaccess file. please suggest to me about this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you enabled it in the backend settings?

Comment: yes, enable it from backend. catgory and product url are working fine but custom brand module url not working.